# Adding a canvas to the mainview in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm working on a singleton Applicatiobar, so I can access it from every class that inherites PhoneApplicationPage, but I want to add a Canvas( or any other UIElement ) to the basic UI, so it must be available through the entire application. Instead of saying: 
`CollectionName.Children.Add( UIElement )` Is there a single class from where I can acces all the elements on the currently active page and add/ remove UIElements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have acces to `PhoneApplicationFrame`:

```
 (App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame)
```

Current page you can get with:

```
var currentPage = ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
```

Comment: Yes, I came this far =) 
So I do get into ( let's say mainpage ), how do I go from there in adding a UIElement to this page ( other than speaking directly to an instance of the mainpage class )?

Comment: Cast `PhoneApplicationPage` to `MainPageClass` and call any method you have there

Comment: okey, so this is basically the same as passing an interface through the parameter of the object that is to call the method in Mainpage?
There is no object that holds ALL pages within the application? So, in other words, which you can call and say: "Whatever page you are holding, I don't care, I want you to place this canvas over that page."

Comment: I don't think that exists such object. You can try to put something to the top of `PhoneApplicationFrame` or handle canvas manually on page that is on the front now.

Comment: okey, thank you =) I think passing an interface would work best, if there is no default function in Silverlight for this.